# Error while unmarshalling the XML string

Tags: java, xml, unmarshalling

I have a XML string which looks like this:

```
 <PIR:Data xmlns:PIR="https://www.google.com">
    <CustomerInfo name="abcd" address="delhi">
 </PIR:Data>
```

Now I am unmarshalling it to the class with the name Data.java which has the variable as another class of CustomerInfo.java.

But while unmarshalling I am getting error as 
unexpected element (uri:"https://www.google/com", local:"Data").Expected elements are <{}customerInfo>

Comment: This error has gone when I have added
    @XmlRootElement(namespace="https://www.google.com", name="Data")
in the Data class. But I am still not getting the values in the fields.

Comment: Your xml incorrect, CustomerInfo should have closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

While unmarshaling  the xml to pojo, xml elements should be correctly mapped in pojo.You must have to give the namespace and xml tag name must match with @XmlElement name. Here is POJO for your xml.It should work.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "customerInfo"     
})

@XmlRootElement(name="Data",namespace = "https://www.google.com")
public class Data{
    @XmlElement(name = "CustomerInfo")
    private CustomerInfo customerInfo;

    public CustomerInfo getCustomerInfo() {
        return customerInfo;
    }

    public void setCustomerInfo(CustomerInfo customerInfo) {
        this.customerInfo = customerInfo;
    }

}
```